# Transformação de texto de e-mail em imagem - PHP e Javascript

Tags: php, imagem, envio-de-email

No meu site (feito em PHP e Javascript), possuo uma rotina de envio de vouchers (é site de um cliente de hotelaria) pro e-mail de hóspede.

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu transformar todo o conteúdo do e-mail que é enviado ao hóspede em uma imagem (JPG, PNG, BMP ou qualquer outro formato).

Comment: No caso seria para ele não alterar o conteúdo do voucher? Tente enviar o voucher em PDF utilizando o [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf). Creio que seja o método mais prático e usual. Abraço

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta não é muito clara. Qual o tipo do conteúdo?

Comment: O conteúdo é texto e algumas imagens. E tem alguns links também. Imagino que o ideal nesse caso seria colocar o mesmo conteúdo do e-mail como um PDF em anexo, pra não perder os links também.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível utilizar a biblioteca [GD](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php) ou [Image Magick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) para manipulação de imagens no PHP.

Primeiramente você precisa de uma imagem base (com o logo do cliente, a arte de fundo, rodapé...). Ai utilizando a GD ou a Image Magick você insere o texto personalizado para cada usuário (link, ou código).
Ai você pode incluir a imagem como anexo no corpo do e-mail, pode enviar o e-mail com a imagem e o source da tag img ser o código em Base 64 da imagem ou pode gerar um arquivo físico dessa imagem e hospedar em seu site e apenas referenciar ela no e-mail ou você pode gerar a imagem sob demanda, isto é, quando o usuário abre o e-mail, ele chama um arquivo.php em seu site que é responsável por escrever em uma imagem ou nome dele e o voucher.

Vou mostrar um exemplo, com o último caso que falei. Você vai enviar o e-mail HTML com uma tag de imagem e o caminho da imagem será um arquivo .php
Vamos utilizar a biblioteca GD para este exemplo.

Crie uma arquivo PHP com o seguinte nome por exemplo: **geraVoucher.php**
Nos e-mails dos clientes coloque o seguinte código:

```
<img src="http://www.seusite.com.br/geraVoucher.php?nomeCliente=Guilherme&voucher=MAIO2015DESCONTO" alt="Seu voucher é MAIO2015DESCONTO" />
```

Repare que tanto o voucher como o nome do cliente está na queryString do arquivo que será carregado como imagem (mas na verdade é um arquivo PHP).
Ai seu arquivo **geraVoucher.php** será o seguinte:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png'); //define o cabeçalho como Imagem / PNG assim o navegador vai reconhecer como imagem e mostrar no corpo do e-mail do usuário.
    $nomeCliente = $_GET["nomeCliente"]; //obtém a queryString com o nome do cliente
    $voucher = $_GET["voucher"]; //obtém a queryString com o código VOUCHER para o cliente
    $imagem = imagecreatefrompng("base.png"); //base.png é a moldura da imagem.
    $preto = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 0, 0, 0); //define a cor "preto"
    $vermelho = imagecolorallocate($imagem, 255, 0, 0); //define a cor "vermelho"
    $fonteCaminho = "/fontes/arial.ttf"; //local onde se encontra o arquivo da fonte TTF (true type font)

    imagettftext($imagem, 25, 0, 15, 50, $preto, $fonteCaminho, "Olá $nomeCliente, seu voucher para desconto é:"); //escreve a primeira linha de texto, com a cor preta, nas coordenadas X->15 e Y->50, com a fonte tamanho 25 e 0 de inclinação.
    imagettftext($imagem, 30, 0, 15, 80, $vermelho, $fonteCaminho, $voucher); //escreve o VOUCHER em uma segunda linha na cor vermelho, nas coordenadas X->15 e Y->80 com fonte tamanho 3,0 e 0 de inclinação.

    /* Porque a segunda linha está nas coordenadas 15x80 ?
       Porque a primeira linha, você escreveu nas coordenadas 15x50 com uma fonte 25, logo vai acabar no pixel 75 (50 + 25) e ai adicionamos 5 pixels de margem. */
    imagepng($imagem);
    imagedestroy($imagem);
?>
```